# Angular Mat datepicker formatting

Tags: angular

I want to show the date in date picker in MON YYYY format. When user clicks on any date I just want to show month and Year and date is of no use for me but I have in database (Oracle) have field as date time, so cannot either pass the date in string format.

Ex: if user selects 11/14/2018 then want to show him date as NOV 2018 but in database I want it as 11/1/2018( need to set date to 1 by default irrespective of date selection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Angular material date picker doesn't have any method or property where we can apply  date format directly but with the help of `@angular/material` library you can customize services for the formatting.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="select date" (dateChange)="onChange($event.value)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp startView="month"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Step1:** Import required class and constant variables.

```
import { NativeDateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, DateAdapter } from "@angular/material";
```

**Step2:** Used NativeDateAdapter class method for formatting.

```
const months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat === 'input') {
      const day = date.getDate();
      const month = date.getMonth();
      const year = date.getFullYear();
      return `${months[month]} ${year}`;
    }
    return date.toDateString();
  }
}
```

**Step3:** Declared date format constant.

```
export const APP_DATE_FORMATS =
{
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' },
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
  }
};
```

**Step4:** Register providers under the component or main module

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter
    },
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS
    }
  ]
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor() { }

  onChange(val) {
    var d = new Date(val);
    let date = [d.getFullYear(), ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), ('01').slice(-2)].join('-');
    console.log(date);
      }
}
```

**Selection**: 02/14/2018

**Display**: Feb 2018

**Output**: 2018-02-01 ( in .ts file)